# In BigQuery can the "INFORMATION_SCHEMA" be added as a DataSet and Pined?

Tags: google-bigquery

Any idea if the INFORMATION_SCHEMA and its contents can be pinned as suggested in the title?

It is nice to be able to query it and all (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables), but it would be very helpful if it can be pinned. I've not been able to find a Doc yet that tells you how or if this can be done.

[bigquery screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSiTl.png)

[bigquery screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amI9c.png)

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I would like to be able to see all of the tables and columns associated with the INFORMATION_SCHEMA. Having them pined would make those details more readily available, which has been helpful in the past when administrating a database.

I guess I could solve this by setting up some BQ jobs and use a SQL script to populate a table on a schedule.  Seems like more work than should be needed to solve this because the metadata exists already and BQ should have the ability to simply enable this (like other enterprise data warehouses do).

Comment: You can already see a list of tables, columns etc. In the bigquery UI, which is basically the same information you would find in the information_schema, so its not clear why you want to see the information_schema itself.